# Как правильнее преобразовать int в double?

Tags: java, математика

У меня есть число int = 105; 1 это доллар а 05 в нем это центы, как правильнее преобразовать их? я пробовал через double но в итоге получил 1.5, а нужно 1.05.

```
summa = 105;
double d = new BigDecimal(summa).divide(new BigDecimal(100)).doubleValue();
System.out.println(d);
```

Comment: https://ideone.com/583KZn

Comment: Все верно, но когда на входе число сто ответ получается 1.0

Comment: а сколько вы хотели?..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Странно, ваш метод должен работать, но можно проще.

```
 int sum = 105;
 double d = sum/100.0;
```